# Why is $\langle S|-\rangle$ not isomorphic to $\langle T|R\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S,T$ be sets with $|S|>|T|$ and $R$ some relations on $T$.
Why is then $\langle S|-\rangle$ not isomorphic to $\langle T|R\rangle$

This came up when I wanted to solve a different problem, [which I also asked on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2747383/506844). Unfortunately, the answers provided used a completely different strategy and I still wonder about how to prove this.

Intuitively its clear, but I look for a clear proof.

Comment: The group <T|R> is a quotient group.  The images of the elements of T generate this quotient group.  So if <T|R> is free then you need less than or equal to |T| generators.  Thus it can't be isomorphic to <S|->.

Comment: @sykh You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @DerekElkins: But that's not a complete answer. You would need to argue that a free group on $\lvert S\rvert$ generators is not generated by any set of size smaller than $S$. If $S$ is uncountable, this is straightforward. Otherwise, it is not so obvious.

Comment: @tomasz All the more reason it should be in the form of an answer so it can be voted on appropriately, comments can be added to it, and it can be updated if necessary.

Comment: @tomasz: The question J.Doe linked to proves this for the case of finite generating sets.  Since J. Doe linked to that question I assumed that he/she was already familiar with this result and that in this problem the generating sets are finite.

Comment: @sykh: I was not criticising you, I was just saying that turning your comment into a good answer would need to be a little bit more elaboration (and implying it's not worth the work since there are already good answers).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the following includes a proof (admittedly, using the axiom of choice) of the closely related fact that free groups are isomorphic only if they are over sets of the sae cardinality.

Assume $\phi\colon\langle T\mid R\rangle\to  \langle S\rangle $ is an isomorphism (or just an epimorphism). Together with the canonical projection $\pi\colon \langle T\rangle\to \langle T\mid R\rangle$, we obtain an onto homomorphism $\phi\circ\pi\colon \langle T\rangle\to \langle S\rangle$.
Let $V$ be an $\Bbb F_2$ vector space of dimension $|S|$. A bijection from $S$ to a basis of $V$ gives rise to an onto homomorphism $\psi\colon \langle S\rangle \to V$.
Then $\psi(\phi(\pi(T)))$ is a generating system of  $V$, hence contains a basis of $V$. We conclude that 
$$ |T|\ge |\psi(\phi(\pi(T)))|\ge \dim V=|S|,$$
contradicting the assumption that $|S|>|T|$.

Answer (score 0):

The group  is a quotient group.  The images of the elements of T generate this quotient group.  If $<T|R>$ is free then any set of free generators has less than or equal to |T| generators.  Thus it can't be isomorphic to $<S|->$.

Comment: Unfortunately I asked this question in order to obtain an alternative proof of the fact that free groups cannot have less generator than the cardinality of their generating set, so this is not helpful to me.

Comment: It does answer the question you asked though.

Comment: you should read the link before answering

Comment: Your comment is not appropriate and is in bad taste.  You are asking for help from people and asking them to give freely of their time.  I answered the question you asked.  I did read the link in your post.  That link has proofs that the rank of a free group is well defined.  Thus, it was reasonable to assume that you asked what you meant and not some other thing.   I suggest taking the time to better phrase questions in the future.  You also have not accepted any of the valid answers that have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little like cheating here, because that is basically an adaptation of the idea provided from an answer to the linked question... but again they say that mathematics is the art of finding good analogies.

Before I start allow me to introduce the commutator subgroup.
For every group $G$ by $G'$ I denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by the elemets of the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ where $x,y \in G$. Such $G'$ is a normal subgroup and $G/G'$ is the *smallest commutative quotient group of $G$*, for more information [take a look at this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup).

Assume that you have an isomorphism 
$$f \colon \langle S | - \rangle \longrightarrow \langle T | R \rangle$$
the this isomorphism should preserve the commutator subgroups, that is 
$$f(\langle S| - \rangle')=\langle T|R\rangle'\ .$$

Because of this we get an isomorphism 
$$\bar f \colon \langle S| - \rangle / \langle S| - \rangle' \longrightarrow \langle T|R\rangle/\langle T|R\rangle'$$
of abelian groups.

With a little effort one can easily prove that the first quotient is isomorphic to the free abelian group with a basis of cardinality $|S|$.

But the second group is generated by $|T|$ elements where $|T| < |S|$. This is an absurd because the cardinality of a basis of a free abelian group is the minimal number of generators for the group, so $\bar f$ cannot be an isomorphism and neither $f$ can.